# .htaccess block local ip address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wampserver

I have 3 applications running on wampserver hosted on our intranet.

I would like to block the access of applications for a certain ip range. So I edited .htaccess files for each application as below. But the application is not blocked.

order deny,allow
allow from 10.212.4.
deny from all

After checking the logs I found that the ip address the client returning was different. Since all our machines use proxy settings by default.

Anyone could help me how to over come this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite to block people based on their "x-forwarded-for" header.  I would not consider this secure though, because these are easy to forge.

See the discussion here:

http://www.110mb.com/forum/empty-t26129.0.html

Comment: Thanks I have used this RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} ^10\.212\.4\.63$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} ^10\.212\.4\.53$ RewriteRule .* - [F] order allow,deny allow from 10.212.4.63 allow from 10.212.4.53 deny from all  but even when I access application from my allowed Ips its giving 403 error